# How can non-polarised light exist?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, electromagnetic-radiation, polarization

Typically unpolarised light is shown like this:
[image]

Basically, from what I've seen, unpolarised light is just a lot of overlapping individual light waves. However, if they truly overlapped, would their electric and magnetic fields not cancel out?

In the picture above, shouldn't there be a net electric field direction (or even 0 in this case - meaning no EM wave?), as $E$ fields can add (as evidenced by circular polarization)? Is it because this net direction would rapidly change throughout the light ray that it's considered non-polarised? But if this cancellation was true, wouldn't that mean that all the intensity and energy of the original waves have been "destroyed"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different polarized components follow each other *in time* and therefore you can not add them all at a given moment.

Usual optical receiver has a large response time compared to the characteristic change time of the polarization and on average (temporal) the light is unpolarized.

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

The unpolarizedness is in a time averaged sense.

At any instant, if you measure the electric field, you have a definite axis for it. But over time, this axis changes in the way described by your diagram such that there is no preferred axis.